# How to use Vue ProxyTables

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I can not seem to get the vue ProxyTable property to work properly with axios. I would like it to work on both the dev and production.

Goal:

```
dev endpoint = localhost:8000/api/api.php
prod endpoint = domain/api/api.php
```

Vue.Config

```
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
          '^/api': {
            target: 'localhost:8000/api',
            ws: true,
            changeOrigin: true
          }
```

My Component

```
this.$axios
  .post('/api/api.php?path=checkToken', JSON.stringify({ token: this.token }))
  .then(response => {
    // Stuff
  })
  .catch(error => alert(error));
```

}

I know I don't have anything in there for my production server, but even on my dev it keeps looking for localhost:8080 which is the default. Can anyone point me in the right direction?